# curl call works, but still returns "Could not resolve host: POST"

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab

I run following script in gitlab's job:

```
after-merge-to-release:
  script:
  - set -x
  - >
    curl\
      --X POST --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:xyz' --header 'Content-Type:application/json'\
      --data '{"id":"'$PROJECT_ID'","name":"'${MOST_RECENT_SPRINT_BRANCH//'origin/'/}'","allowed_to_push":[{"access_level":0}],"allowed_to_merge":[{"access_level":0}]}'\
      https://git.xyz.net/api/v4/projects/"$PROJECT_ID"/protected_branches
```

I can confirm this command works (it adds a new protected branch to my project), but gitlab's output doesn't confirm it:

```
$ curl\ # collapsed multi-line command
 ++ echo '$ curl\ # collapsed multi-line command'
 ++ curl --X POST --header PRIVATE-TOKEN:xyz --header Content-Type:application/json --data '{"id":"123","name":"origin/sprint/48","allowed_to_push":[{"access_level":0}],"allowed_to_merge":[{"access_level":0}]}' https://git.xyz.net/api/v4/projects/123/protected_branches
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
 100   530  100   413  100   117   3152    893 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4045
```

Why it doesn't return the response from curl request and throws `Could not resolve host: POST` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
--X POST
```

Use only a single dash before `X` to select the http method:

```
-X POST
```